# Generating zip code based start urls in Scrapy

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, scrapy

I need to generate start_urls in my scraper where Scrapy will fill in zip codes.  I'm okay with the lost ones that don't generate actual zip codes, as long as they follow the ##### format (I don't think Scrapy would take long to check 100k pages...)
I found this on another question, and I'm hoping it would work with minimal editing. (Or is there a better convention in scrapy for doing this?)

```
class ExampleSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "test_code"
    allowed_domains = ["www.example.com"]

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in xrange(100000):
            yield self.make_requests_from_url("http://www.example.com/zipcode/%d/search.php" % i)
```

What do I have to change to make it fill out all five digits (00014, e.g.)?  Will the code work as it is like that?  Also, I need another (separate) one to fill in the state name.  Similarly, unless there's an efficient way to tell Python to fill in state abbreviations, I'm okay with the lost abbreviations.  So, e.g., www.example.com/AL/search.php and www.example.com/GA/search.php, etc.  I just want it to autofill those two letters with any two letters - how do I fill in def start_requests(self) for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For zip codes, make it `"%05d"`; this will tell the formatter to pad, using zeros, to five characters.

For states, I suggest iterating over a list:

```
for state in ["AL", "GA", ...]:
    # use state: "www.example.com/%s/search.php" % state
```